# My textbox is not autocompleting with the AutoComplete Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Markup:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server"/> 
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="tbSearch_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
        DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ScriptPath="AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="tbSearch">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
    <asp:Button Text="Find" OnClick="btnFind" runat="server"/>
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

The service is working,  but nothing happens when I change the text inside the text box.
Here is my web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:1784/WebSite10/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService {
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of your service

Comment: How do you know "the web service is working"? Are you verifying that through an inspector (chrome, firebug, etc)

Comment: In What format your web service return Data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service should be referenced in the ServicePath property of the auto complete extender, not the ScriptPath property.  See this example:  http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

HTH.